# Unable to create new folders on Ubuntu and Permissions tab is all greyed out

Tags: 12.04, permissions, directory

I freshly installed Ubuntu with lighttpd; I want to add a test file to check if my server works or not.

I am, however, unable to create files: when I right clicked and opened the "Permissions" tab I don't have any options which can be changed, everything is grayed out and it says `root` is the owner to the files.

How do I set the appropriate permissions?

Comment: Where do you want to create folders?

Answer (score 3):

Where do you want to create a new folder?

By the way, always you can do as root by running a command in terminal by using Sudo:

```
sudo mkdir you_folder_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Facing same due to Windows as second OS

Check your **partition number** in which you face issue...and then use **ntfsfix** command
[image]
(In my case you can see SecondHardDisk shows /dev/sda5 and mount button on the right. So, 5 is my partition number, find yours)

```
sudo fdisk -l
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda5
```

Then simplily mount hardrive

Comment: It works for me thanks.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the ownership of the folder, use:

`chown <new owner's user name>[:group] <folder>`.

To *recursively* assign new ownership on a folder and it's contents, Use `chown -R <new owner's user name>:[group] <folder>`

Answer (score 0):

If the option of New Folder is greyed out. Then Open the "Disks" from the menu.
And select the partition in which you are not able to make new folder.
After that select option of "Repair Filesystem".
This will repair your partition and fix the issue.

That worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to create new folder you can log in as root.

```
sudo -s
```

and create new folder where do you want. Or you can try this command:

```
sudo mkdir folder_name
```

Answer (score -1):

Boot Windows and run filesystem checks on the NTFS partitions. Make sure you shutdown Windows completely, unmounting all file systems.

Linux can't mount NTFS partitions if Windows is (semi-)hibernated.

Comment: How did you conclude that OP's issue related to an  NTFS instance or that Windows is installed on the same machine? -1